# Still struggling with class scope

Tags: python, class, scope

I am still not fully understanding the scope of classes very well.  I have read up on this and and I have been trying to do different things to lean with some success but this one has me scratching my head.  I am playing around with this code. I think Bryan Oakley may have written this example but not positive.

Basically, it is a paging example.  I have added the buttoncontroloff and buttoncontrolon functions to try and control the state of the menu buttons.  I tried this in the Page1 class but that didn't work.

```
class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, MainMenu, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="red")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)
        main = MainView()
        main.buttoncontrolon()
```

I do disable one of the buttons on start so I have part of this. But I can't figure it out when I am trying to do this between two classes. When you click on Page 2 button I just want the Page 1 button to be enabled.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()


class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="red")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="blue")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=lambda: p1.lift())
        self.b1.pack(side="left")
        self.b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=lambda: p2.lift())
        self.b2.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

    def buttoncontroloff(self):
        self.b1.config(state = DISABLED)

    def buttoncontrolon(self):
        self.b1.config(state = NORMAL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.buttoncontroloff()
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For OOPs in Python I would like to suggest you [Learning Python](http://it-ebooks.info/book/2576/) by Mark Lutz, I found it very very helpful.

Comment: I have been going through the book online called Dive into Python.

Comment: that is good book too (I read few chapters from DivPython too),  Learning Python explain OOPs using Attribute Inheritance Search Tree every where and that is really very helpful - tell you how python class scope works... but it teach very slow... Give it a Try!!

Comment: For whatever book you choose, and online resources, I suggest reading a Python 3 book (with possibly differences with Python 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way: write a method in `MainView` for opening a numbered page (0 ...):

```
def open_page(self, page_number):
    # enable all except the button for this page.
    for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
        if i == page_number:
            button.config(state=DISABLED)
        else:
            button.config(state=ACTIVE)

    self.pages[page_number].lift()
```

Make the buttons use this method passing in the page number, as their commands:

```
self.b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, 
    text="Page 1", command=lambda: self.open_page(0))
self.b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, 
    text="Page 2", command=lambda: self.open_page(1))
```

Then make all pages and buttons go into these lists:

```
p1 = Page1(self)
p2 = Page2(self)
self.pages = [ p1, p2 ]
```

and

```
self.buttons = [ self.b1, self.b2 ]
```

Remember that lists use 0-based indexing. Now this would be later easy to refactor into having an `add_page` that would create a button for a page, and put both into the list etc.

The `Page`s do not need to be concerned about `Button`s themselves; it is not their area of responsibility, and the `Button`s do not belong to them.

Comment: I fixed this line... for i, button in enumerate(self.page_buttons): Made it just for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):

Comment: The error on the ENABLED line is odd. Still trying to see what that is about.

Comment: because there is no Tkinter variable named ENABLED. See, I didn't see your answer; you need to comment under *my* answer for me to see any notification.

Comment: use `NORMAL` instead of `ENABLED`, I remembered Tk wrong

Comment: It should be ACTIVE. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Antti, I fixed the errors. This code below works great!  I will mark your solution as answered. BIG thanks again.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="red")


class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="blue")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        self.pages = [ p1, p2 ]

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=lambda: self.open_page(0))
        self.b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=lambda: self.open_page(1))
        self.b2.pack(side="left")
        self.b1.pack(side="left")
        self.buttons = [ self.b1, self.b2 ]

        p1.show()


    def open_page(self, page_number):
        # enable all except the button for this page.
        for i, button in enumerate(self.page_buttons):
            if i == page_number:
                button.config(state=DISABLED)
            else:
                button.config(state=ACTIVE)
        self.pages[page_number].lift()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    #main.buttoncontroloff()
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is a pretty obvious error, where do you see any attribute `page_buttons` in the class? I imagine it should be buttons, you will also get an error with ENABLED

Comment: Also what is `ctlbuttons` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Padraic, that is left over junk from my attempt to get it working from the original code.

Comment: remove whatever junk is not needed